# loading html page into rails server

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I created the whole responsive site in notepad - shop.html. I
can see its directory in rails. Put all my files in public folder of its rails app. Now I dont know how to load it in localhost:3000. How do i do that. Have configured everything. Rails server is running and It shows only the default index.html file. But when i write rails generate controller eshop. It says uninitialized constant welcome error. 
PS: i m new to ruby.
All guides show how to create a new app but I couldnt find a way to load a html page already created in editor to load in browser using rails server.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I m using Linux mint, rails 4 and everything is updated with all gems

Comment: yep, just did. it says : "no route matches [GET] "/shop.html".  It is giving me a Routes helper where It is asking me to provide a path/url. I tried copying the path from the directory but it say Path Matching (/eshop/public): No matches found.

Comment: You didn't even read any rails tutorial, did you?

Comment: Read about ruby on rails views first, bro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you generated a controller you need to put the content from your `shop.html` file into the `/views/eshop/index.html.erb` file

Open the routes file under `config/routes.rb` and change the following line

from:

```
root "welcome#index"
```

to:

```
root "eshop#index"
```

this way your app will point to the right file.

---

Subsequently you could just point the root to the `shop.html` file which I do not recommend. However you should definitely look into routing in rails and how it works.

Comment: If it worked make sure to mark the answer as correct